# Space between links in navigation

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I made a horizontal navigation, but I want there to be some space between the left and right link. [my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QK3j.png) 
I can't figure it out how to do that. This is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.navigation-homepage ul,
a {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-homepage">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none"> Home </a> <br> </li>
    <li> <a href="collection.html" style="text-decoration: none"> Collection </a> <br> </li>
    <li> <a href="about%20this%20website.html" style="text-decoration: none"> About this website </a> <br> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: This is how I see it in fullscreen: https://prnt.sc/qmfdbu You might want to decrease the font-size for mobile view: https://prnt.sc/qmfdsk using media queries.

Comment: There is allready a space between the left and right link

Comment: I think I explained it wrong. I'm sorry. I don't want them so close to the edge. I posted a better picture.

Comment: so add just margin to the container itself `margin: 0 20px 0 20px;`

Answer (score 0):

You could add some margin to the left and the right of your container:

```css
.navigation-homepage ul, a {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 42px;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navigation-homepage {
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation-homepage">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="index.html" style="text-decoration: none"> Home </a> <br> </li>
    <li> <a href="collection.html" style="text-decoration: none"> Collection </a> <br> </li>
    <li> <a href="about%20this%20website.html" style="text-decoration: none"> About this website </a> <br> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```